# Unable connect SQL Server in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, database

I'm unable to connect sql-server in Laravel. I have given sqlserver config value in .env but still getting below the error when running command 'php artisan migrate'.

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))
```

Review below the database connection configuration in .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-1CGE50Q  #I have also tried here to passing system IPv4
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=laravel_dev
DB_USERNAME=DESKTOP-1CGE50Q\Dell
DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
<?php 
$serverName = "DESKTOP-1CGE50Q, 1433"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"laravel_dev", "UID" => "DESKTOP-1CGE50Q\Dell"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
?>
```

I have setup Laravel site in IIS server and it's working fine. Just issue with sqlServer connection.

Let me know if anyone have any solution or idea about above concern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL server using other tools?

Comment: if the sql server is on another computer, you will need to open the firewall

Comment: If it is remote connection there are few steps you need to make before you will be able to connect. Here is documentation about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Aro No, I'm not using any other tool. 
I have tried to connect using PHP script but still getting the same error. Review below the scipt and response.
===========
<?php
$serverName = "DESKTOP-1CGE50Q, 1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"laravel_dev",  "UID" => "DESKTOP-1CGE50Q\Dell");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
============
Response:
[0] => 08001
[SQLSTATE] => 08001
[1] => 10061
[code] => 10061
[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: @nbk I am trying in local system and sql-server in my local system.

Comment: Are you sure that DB_HOST is correct?

Comment: Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed? It doesn't come with Windows.

Comment: @Aro Yes, 'DESKTOP-1CGE50Q' this the server name of SQL server. I have also tried by giving system IPv4 at the DB_HOST  but still unable to connect.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, I have installed it.

Comment: you need to ürovide authenfication like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php  or the conntstring taht fits. First download ssms and see if you can connect with it

Comment: Have you configured your local SQL Server to allow TCP/IP connections? Run this from a command prompt to verify port connectivity: `powershell -Command "tnc DESKTOP-1CGE50Q -Port 1433"`

Comment: @nbk I have already downloaded, installed and setup 'ssms' successfully. While connecting this I'm using 'window authenticate' and connect server successfully without asking username-password.

Comment: according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16  you have a uid too much in your connection strind

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, I have enabled tcp/ip for sql server configuration but while hitting command as you have given I'm getting error:
 WARNING: TCP connect to (my-ip : 1433) failed 
|| PingSucceeded          : True ||
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

Comment: @nbk Okay, Let me try with 'SQL Server Authentication' if it works.

Comment: @JitendraHengada, you will not be able to connect with TCP/IP if the port test fails. It's likely blocked by firewall.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your instance is listening on the tcp/1433 port. If you open SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager and go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (your instance name) then: 1) is the TCP/IP protocol enabled? 2) if you go into the properties of the TCP/IP protocol which TCP Ports are shown as Active+Enabled?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, TCP/IP protocol is enabled.

Comment: @DanGuzman Now connected with tcp/ip 'TcpTestSucceeded : True'.

Comment: @JitendraHengada, it's not clear what changed to make the TCP/IP port test successful. Does the SQL connection work with `$serverName = "DESKTOP-1CGE50Q,1433"`?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is fixed and here is solution.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/47937

Also, it works with Windows Authentication.
Thanks.